# auto increase all fields that has a field with a value less than an introduced value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help creating this sql procedure: Create a procedure to auto increase all fields that has a field with a value less than an introduced value, then print out how many times each row has been updated.

```
begin

DECLARE veces int(2);
SET veces = 1;

while (totalbonus < 100 )
do
update resumenbonus set totalbonus = totalbonus+punto where codalumno in (select codalumno from resumenbonus where totalbonus < 100);
SET veces = veces + 1;


end while;
select concat("se ha actualizado " , veces, " veces", codalumno);
end
```

This is the table:

```
codalumno totalbonus

    CD456 5

    EF789 48

    JK123 100
```

I need to update both CD456 and EF789 till both have a totalbonus of  at least 100, and then print out how many times each has been updated.

Comment: Please do your homework by your own

Comment: I have been searching for ages. cant you be more helpful?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? That code wont run on both.

Comment: @jarlh Hi, I'm using MySQL. I dont know how to update all records that satisfy the condition while still being able to print out how many times each record has been update. The totalbonus will be different from each record.

Comment: Please provide `resumenbonus` or an alternative. Also, remove SQL-Server tag.